# Manage who can see the feedback from other users on the google play store app page

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed an android application. I want to upload it to the google play store from where users can download it and use. I have included Rate us option in my application which will take users to the apps page on the play store where they can rate and add a feedback. I dont want users to see other users' comments and rating for various reasons. The feedback they give should only be visible to me and the user who wrote it and no one else. Is that possible? Are there any privacy settings through which I will be able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The rate option will open the google play app's page in some kind of webview, so you can not change it.

**So the answer is *NO***